# Java Scanner について

Tags: java

```
IPHONE 7, 4.7, A10, GSM, JET BLACK, 32GB, TRUE, 700
IPAD AIR 2, 9.7, A8, TRUE, SILVER, 64GB, 400
```

以上の文章に対し、 `Scanner.delimiter(",")`を用いて一文字づつ読み取りたいのですが、文章の最後尾になると `700 IPAD AIR 2,` というように行を変えなが読み取ってしまいます。どのようにすれば最後尾に行替えをしないようにすることができるでしょうか？

Comment: [Scanner.useDelimiter (Java Platform SE 8)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter-java.util.regex.Pattern-) を使って、`.useDelimiter("\\s*(^|,|\r?\n|$)\\s*")` とするなど。

Comment: @metropolis コメント欄は回答欄ではないです

Answer (score 2):

改行もdelimiterに加えてください。

```
useDelimiter(",|\n")
```